# Concatenate many rows into a single text string with grouping

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql, string-concatenation

I have the following table: tblFile

[image: tblFile]

My Desired output:

[image]

I am Concatenating many rows into a single text string; however, I cannot get the grouping correct. As the code is now it will just display for each record in the FileNameString field: AAA,BBB,CCC,DDD,EEE,FFF

Any suggestions with the grouping!

```sql
SELECT FileID, Stuff(
(SELECT     N', ' + CONVERT(Varchar, FileName) 
FROM         tblFile  FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE )
.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,2,N'')AS FileNameString 
From tblFile
GROUP BY FileID
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

try this -

```
SELECT DISTINCT
      fileid
    , STUFF((
        SELECT N', ' + CAST([filename] AS VARCHAR(255))
        FROM tblFile f2
        WHERE f1.fileid = f2.fileid ---- string with grouping by fileid
        FOR XML PATH (''), TYPE), 1, 2, '') AS FileNameString
FROM tblFile f1
```

Comment: Replacing first char with nothing is incorrect way

Comment: I received an Error: Argument data type xml is invalid for argument 1 of stuff function ..

Comment: Remove the TYPE parameter for a working version. TYPE causes the result to be returns as an XML data type, but STUFF needs a string.