# Combining values of column based on similar rows in SQL

Tags: sql-server

I have the following SQL table

```
 Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5
 1       | Alex    | Summers |   78    | varbinary content of File1.txt
 2       | Steve   | Jones   |   26    | varbinary content of File2.txt
 3       | Steve   | Jones   |   26    | varbinary content of File3.txt
 4       | Steve   | Jones   |   26    | varbinary content of FileX.txt
 5       | Shai    | Agassi  |   33    | varbinary content of File5.txt
 6       | Shai    | Agassi  |   33    | varbinary content of File8.txt
 7       | Nora    | Akeel   |   90    | varbinary content of File11.txt
```

I would like to create a new table with same columns but rows aggregated such that if columns values of 2nd 3rd and 4th are same, then I would like to combine the varbinary contents of column5. That is

```
 Column1 | Column2 | Column3 | Column4 | Column5
 1       | Alex    | Summers |   78    | varbinary content of File1.txt
 2       | Steve   | Jones   |   26    | varbinary content of File2.txt File3.txt FileX.txt
 3       | Shai    | Agassi  |   33    | varbinary content of File5.txt File8.txt
 4       | Nora    | Akeel   |   90    | varbinary content of File11.txt
```

I can combine the contents of varbinary using a C# program but was just wondering if there is any SQL function I could use to know which rows I need to combine.

Comment: Which SQL engine? MSSQL?

Comment: You can create a view and use pure SQL to solve this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362653/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string-with-grouping and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server for more.