# Any string concatenation method in slick groupBy?

Tags: scala, playframework, slick

I am trying to apply `.groupBy` in a Slick query

```
var q = (for {
      user <- Users
      userSettings <- UserSettings if user.id === userSettings.userId
    } yield (user, userSettings)).groupBy {
      case (users, userSettings) =>
        (user.id, userSettings.controls)
    }.map {
      case (x, y) => (x._1, y.map(_._2.controls).???)
    }
```

If the `controls` column was an Integer or Long, I could apply `sum`, `avg` and other aggregate functions. But in this case `controls` is a string. How to group concatenate these strings so that records look like

```
-----------------------------------------
|User ID    |User Controls              |
-----------------------------------------
|1          |left, right, up, down      |
|2          |left, right                |
-----------------------------------------
```

without applying `groupBy` records look like this

```
-----------------------------------------
|User ID    |User Controls              |
-----------------------------------------
|1          |left                       |
|1          |right                      |
|1          |up                         |
|1          |down                       |
|2          |left                       |
|2          |right                      |
-----------------------------------------
```

Comment: There is an issue where support for backend-specific aggregation functions is discussed: https://github.com/slick/slick/issues/923

If you happen to be using postgres, there is an extension to slick that adds support for these functions: https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slick takes your Scala code and converts it to SQL, so anything you do in Slick must be supported by the underlying SQL. If you search for similar questions related to concatenating strings in SQL, you [find some results on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362653/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string-with-grouping). Unfortunately, it is non trivial to do this kind of thing in SQL. (*Note: It is possible in some SQL dialects.*) There may be some Slick driver that exposes SQL-dialect specific functions, or something that executes after the SQL query, but you can simply take your query, and run the groupBy/map after executing it against the DB, such as by doing:

```
val q = for {
  user <- Users
  userSettings <- UserSettings if user.id === userSettings.userId
} yield (user.id, userSettings.controls)
val db = Database.forConfig("h2mem1")
try {
  for {
    res <- db.run(q.result)
  } yield res
    .groupBy(_._1)
    .map({ case (id, t) => id -> t.map(_._2).mkString(", ") })
} finally db.close
```

Comment: I want to apply searching sorting before running `db.run`

Comment: IIRC — If the rows are sorted when they come back from `db.run`, Scala's groupBy() should maintain the ordering within the groupings.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, noticed no support for this. In this case, we can use raw queries with proper validation and sanitization.

Suppose, I have a table named `logs` (id, message, date). I want to group by date and contact each group message. So my query will be:

```
def histogram(data: ReqData): Future[Vector[DbHistogramMapper]] = {

    var messageWild = s"%${data.phrase}%"
    /**Need to write raw query because there is no support for GROUP_CONCAT in slick*/
    val query = sql"""SELECT "date" AS date, GROUP_CONCAT("message") AS message FROM "logs" WHERE "date" >= ${data.datetimeFrom} AND "date" <= ${data.datetimeUntil} AND "message" LIKE  ${messageWild} GROUP BY "date" """.as[DbHistogramMapper]
    db.run(query)
  }
```

Note: DbHistogramMapper

```
case class DbHistogramMapper(
     date: Timestamp,
     message: String
)
```