# (SQL Server) Merge rows with character and binary

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

Can Somebody teach me how to merge the column 1 row into the same value and the column 2 row join together with binary and character?

For example : (TABLE A)

```
column1       column2

1              james
1              12345
2              jane
2              54321
```

to

```
1            james,12345
2            jane,54321
```

Your answer would be appreciated!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [GROUP BY to combine/concat a column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15154644/group-by-to-combine-concat-a-column)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273238/how-to-use-group-by-to-concatenate-strings-in-sql-server

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362653/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string-with-grouping

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2046037/can-i-comma-delimit-multiple-rows-into-one-column

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/194852/concatenate-many-rows-into-a-single-text-string

Answer (score 2):

SQL Sever in Use Stuff Query to merge.

```
SELECT column1, 
    column2 = STUFF((SELECT ',' + column2 FROM Testing1 as t1 where
     t1.column1=t2.column1  FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') 
FROM Testing1 as t2 GROUP BY column1
```

Comment: Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The data types varchar and sql_variant are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: you need to cast, which data type you use saw me.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       Rs.Col1,
       STUFF(
            (
                SELECT ','+CAST(Column2 AS NVARCHAR)
                FROM TableA
                WHERE Col1 = Rs.Col1 FOR XML PATH('')
            ), 1, 1, '') AS Field
FROM TableA Rs;
```

Comment: Shown 'The data types varchar and sql_variant are incompatible in the add operator.'

Comment: Edited to cast the sql_variant as nvarchar

Answer (score 0):

Following query will answer your Question for MySQL.

```
 SELECT column_1,GROUP_CONCAT(column_2) FROM your_table GROUP BY column_1
```

`column_1` have repeated value so you can perform group by on that column and the `GROUP_CONCAT(column_2)` will produce output as you desire by combining the value of `column_2` using comma.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT not exist

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple approach is to use `STUFF()` function :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
       T.column1,
       [column2] = STUFF(
                        (
                            SELECT ', '+column2
                            FROM <table_name>
                            WHERE column1 = T.column1
                            ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY column1 ORDER BY column2 DESC) FOR XML PATH('')
                        ), 1, 1, '')
FROM <table_name> T;
```

Result :

```
column1 column2
1       james, 12345
2       jane, 54321
```

Comment: Msg 402, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
The data types varchar and sql_variant are incompatible in the add operator.

Comment: @Gug-HongJang In order to avoid the error message you should cast the sql_variant variable to the desired  data type.